# redirect to a new page from an an observable method

Tags: angular

I have a service that gets settings of an app from pouchdb:

```
settings(): Observable<any> {
    let vm = this;
    return new Observable(observer => {
        vm.pouch.get("_local/info", function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                observer.error({'setup': 0});
                observer.complete();  
            } else {
                observer.next(doc);
                observer.complete();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I call the method from other components and services as follows:

```
this.settingService.settings().subscribe(data=>
    {},
    err => {
        //redirect to settings page/component
        vm.router.navigate(["settings"]);
    },
    () => {}
);
```

I was wondering if I can redirect from settings() itself when there is an error? While it works, I am not sure what is happening to the components that subscribe to settings()?

Comment: just a comment, why do you use `vm`? You are using fat arrow syntax in most of places, at least where you would use `this`, so the scope of `this` should be fine, unless we are not seeing all code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine. Here's what is happening after your redirect:

- because of the error, the subscription stops
- the redirect to another page cause the components in your current page to destroy

Just a small note outside of the question: navigate by using `vm.router.navigate(["/settings"])` if you are redirecting to a parent route.

Answer (score 0):

You can `map/tap` into `Observable` that is returned by `settings()` eg

```
public settings():Observable{

    var obs= // whatever you did to generate Observable here in the first place 
    return obs.pipe(
              tap((val)=>val, (err)=>doRedirect))
}
```